# ASP.NET REST POST - JavaScript (jQuery) Send Body in POST

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, rest, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a REST call that is working fine when I call it from a C# app, but I can't make my JavaScript page send the content in the body of the POST. This is the REST controller. Note the JavaScript below works fine if I remove the "FromBody" attribute from the call.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AuthenticateController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post([FromBody] CredentialsModel credentialsModel)
    {
        var authenticationModel = new AuthenticationModel { IsSuccess = false };

        if (credentialsModel != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentialsModel.Username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentialsModel.Password))
        {
            authenticationModel = SecurityBusinessLayer.IsValidUser(credentialsModel.Username, credentialsModel.Password);
        }

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(authenticationModel, new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects, ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize });

        return Content(json);
    }
}
```

This is the JavaScript using JQuery:

```
function authenticate(username, password)
{
    //Get the authenticate api url
    var uriHref = window.location.href;
    var lastIndexOfSlash = uriHref.lastIndexOf('/');
    var apiPath = uriHref.substring(0, lastIndexOfSlash) + "/api";
    var encodedUri = encodeURI(apiPath + "/authenticate/");

    var credentials = {};
    credentials["Username"] = username;
    credentials["Password"] = password;

    //Post the username and password to the server
    $.post(encodedUri, credentials, function (data)
    {
        //Parse the returned data (should match Adapt.Data.Generic.AuthenticationModel)
        var response = JSON.parse(data);

        if (response.IsSuccess)
        {
            //Ensure the token will expire
            var expiryDate = new Date();
            expiryDate = new Date(expiryDate.setTime(expiryDate.getTime() + 86400000));

            //Set the auth token cookie
            var cookieString = "authToken=" + response.Authtoken + "; expires=" + expiryDate.toUTCString() + ";path=/";
            document.cookie = cookieString;

            //Goto the xivic app page
            window.location = "Index.html";
        }
        else
        {
            //Failed to log in, show error message
            $("#badLoginMessage").css("visibility", "visible");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `credentials` object must be stringified, `JSON.stringify(credentials)`

Comment: I did try that. I will try again though.

Comment: @ibubi I tried your suggestion but it made no difference.

Comment: @ibubi , your suggestion, in combination with Le Tung Anh's code snippet fixes the problem. I checked the transfer with fiddler and realised that the $post call was not setting the content type to 'application/json'. So, I switched the code to use $.ajax instead and manually set the content type. I am going to post the working code snippet. First person to post the full answer gets the rep.

Comment: @LeTungAnh, care to take another stab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working code based on @LeTungAnh, and @ibubi's code. I can't help but think that $post would still be a better method though. The reason $post was not working was that it was not sending a content type of application/json which is what ASP.NET Core requires.

```
function authenticate(username, password) {
    //Get the authenticate api url
    var uriHref = window.location.href;
    var lastIndexOfSlash = uriHref.lastIndexOf('/');
    var apiPath = uriHref.substring(0, lastIndexOfSlash) + "/api";
    var encodedUri = encodeURI(apiPath + "/authenticate/");

    var credentials = {};
    credentials["Username"] = username;
    credentials["Password"] = password;

    var credentialsJson = JSON.stringify(credentials);

    $.ajax({
        url: encodedUri,
        type: 'POST',
        data: credentialsJson,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (responseJson) {

            var authenticationObject = JSON.parse(responseJson)

            if (authenticationObject.IsSuccess == true) {

                //Ensure the token will expire
                var expiryDate = new Date();
                expiryDate = new Date(expiryDate.setTime(expiryDate.getTime() + 86400000));

                //Set the auth token cookie
                var cookieString = "authToken=" + authenticationObject.Authtoken + "; expires=" + expiryDate.toUTCString() + ";path=/";
                document.cookie = cookieString;

                //Goto the xivic app page
                window.location = "Index.html";
            }
            else {
                //Failed to log in, show error message
                $("#badLoginMessage").css("visibility", "visible");
            }

        },
        error: function () {
            //Failed to log in, show error message
            $("#badLoginMessage").css("visibility", "visible");
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you remove [FromBody, you have to post Json object instead of array]

```html
$.ajax({
                url: encodedUri,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    Username: jsonString,Password:password
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.Success == true) {
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       
                    }

                },
                error: function () {

                },
                complete: function () {
                }
            });
```

Comment: I didn't remove the FromBody. It's right there in my sample.